# How to config Django-haystack so "content" searched still shows results in the search field

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack-solr and ajax. When a client types in the search field, results matching it dispaly in a drop down box. the thing is solr also searches my content. So if a client types in pasta primavera and its in the content and not the title it doesnt show any result for that. How do I make it so the post title shows even though the query is in the content? To be clear, if I type in pasta primavera and its not a post.title but in the post.content of the post, I still want the post.title to be displayed. What is the correct syntax to get this result? The following is my code

my search_index.py

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
        text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
        title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
        content = indexes.CharField(model_attr='content')
        publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')
        slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')

        content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')

        def get_model(self):
            return Post

        def index_queryset(self, using=None):
            """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
            return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

my views.py

```
def search_title(request):
posts = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('search_text', '')).order_by('-publish')
context = {
    "posts": posts
}
# context.update(csrf(request))
return render(request, "posts/ajax_search.html", {"posts": posts})
```

my post_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.content }}
```

my ajax_search.html

```
{% if posts.count > 0 %}
<div class="result-box" id="cell">
{% for post in posts %}

<li><a href="{% url 'posts:detail' post.slug %}" id="fix" class="list-group-item">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
<li class="list-group-item" id="none"> None to show</li>

{% endif %}
</div>
```

all guidance is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet()
  sqs1 = sqs.autocomplete(title_auto=query).order_by('-publish')
  sqs2 = sqs.autocomplete(content_auto=query).order_by('-publish')

  posts = sqs1 | sqs2
```

Answer (score 0):

The field that is searched during autocomplete search is configured with this line of your code:

```
content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
```

I have not done it using the haystack classes (always configuring my own handler on the SOLR side), but I think you just have to configure two fields:

```
title_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')
```

And add another field to your query:

```
query = request.GET.get('search_text', None)
if query:
    # updated according to losee's comment
    sqs1 = sqs.autocomplete(title_auto=query).order_by('-publish')
    sqs2 = sqs.autocomplete(content_auto=query).order_by('-publish')

    posts = sqs1 | sqs2
```

SearchQuerySet.autocomplete() source code:
https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/query.py#L448

Note: You will have to add that new field into your SOLR schema.

---

#### SOLR only solution

If you are familiar enough with SOLR, here another way to do it:

You already have the field `content_auto` in your solr schema. Add the following to your schema:

```
<copyField source="content" dest="content_auto" />
```

Reindex. Then your current code should work.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did what you said but it doesn't work. It's either autocomplete(title_auto=query) or autocomplete(content_auto=query) if I use both it won't work